# Master Detail menu as secondary menu

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I currently have a tabbed Page as my root page for IOS. But i don't want to add a lot of tabs, so i was wondering how i would go about opening a master detail page as a secondary menu? Kind of like the "More" tab on the Facebook IOS app.

Here is my IOS root page:

```
   class RootPageIOS : TabbedPage
{
    public RootPageIOS()
    {
        NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);

        Children.Add(new FeedReaderNavigationPage(new HomePage()));
        Children.Add(new FeedReaderNavigationPage(new MyLocation()));
        Children.Add(new FeedReaderNavigationPage(new Feeds()));
        Children.Add(new FeedReaderNavigationPage(new SettingsPage()));
    }
}
```

So when i click on the Settings Page tab, i want a master details page to appear.

Any help/suggestions?

Thank you.

Comment: I would not recommend to use MasterDetail page inside of TabbedPage, because it's not fully supported: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=38397

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is not possible because you cannot have two root pages attached to App.MainPage property. What you can do is you could change the app main page into master detail page on click ok Settings page Then.. on back press of Settings page change the main page into your tabbed page.

Edited...
Another option would be have MasterDetail page as app main page and Add your tabbed page to the Detail page of MasterDetailPAge